# Play Framework 2.4.6 Call JavaScript

Tags: java, playframework-2.4

I'm very new to play and have a question. How can I make a simple HTML call to a JavaScript file.

`main.scala.html` file and JavaScript file.

```
document.body.onload = test;

function test(){
    alert("Hallo");
}
```

```html
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/se2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src ="se2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my routs

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your `se2.js` is in correct path, then just call the `test()` function like...

```
...
<body>
    <script>test();</script>
</body>
...
```

Comment: dosnt work for any reason. here my path: /home/raul/workspace/rto/public/javascripts/se2.js

Comment: Use browser inspection tools to check if browser is able to find the script, also check the generated HTML in you head you should have line: `<script src="/assets/javascripts/se2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` check if script is available at http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/se2.js

Comment: sorry, I forgot to insert the /se2.js in the adress bar. Yes the the script in there.

Comment: here the inspected links: http://127.0.0.1:9001/assets/javascripts/se2.js - https://pl.vc/1p1y4 ; http://127.0.0.1:9001/assets/javascripts/se2.js and http://127.0.0.1:9001/ - https://pl.vc/2fzec ;

Comment: at the second screenshot - there where is Inspector tool showed I can see that your `head` section is empty and there is no `<script>` part in the body, only push btn, do you use proper view in your action?

Comment: what you mean by "proper view"? btw, the push btn is created with java and returned from Application class as String.

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` section in the `<body>` tag is redundant. What you should do is just load the main page localhost:9000 and not the assets page. This way it should execute the script when the page is loaded. I tested this with your scripts and everything worked. 
Can you also paste your controller method?

Comment: I found it out. I forgot in the Application class to set the return to views.html.index.render. Now it works. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You allowed the access to your public folder with your routes:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

This is an example for call it in the html:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

You define in the routs that you can enter the public folder with /assets.